# Operação de datadiff no SQL 2014

Tags: mysql, sql

Tenho uma base acumulada de datas no sql, eu queria selecionar todas as datas que tiverem da data atual (hoje) até 60 dias atrás, mas não estou conseguindo acertar o código.

```
***select
    data
    CPF,
    sum(risco) as risco
    from BASE_ACUMULADA
    where  Data in (datediff(dd, 0, getdate())),(datediff(dd, 0, getdate())-60))
    group by data, CPF***
```

Answer (score -1):

Experimente essa sugestão utilizando o operador *Between*:

```
where Data between dateadd(dd, -60, cast(getdate() as date)) and getdate()
```

Espero que ajude